# difference of true or false in variable

Tags: javascript

```js
let names = [];
let isOver = false;

while (!isOver) {
  let name = prompt("Enter another name or press cancel.");

  if (name != null) {
    names.push(name);
  } else {
    isOver = true;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  console.log(names[i]);
}
```

If I change the vaiable 'isOver' value to true, I will also change the while condition to (isOver) and else to isOver = false;

```js
let names = [];
let isOver = true;

while (isOver) {
  let name = prompt("Enter another name or press cancel.");

  if (name != null) {
    names.push(name);
  } else {
    isOver = false;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  console.log(names[i]);
}
```

I just want to know why used 'false' in the first place?

Comment: there is no *practical* difference here, both versions will lead to the same result, it's just a choice even though the original version seems more *logical* due to the naming (while NOT OVER keep going).

Comment: Because of the semantic of the varible, it is counterintuitive to exit a loop if a variable named "isOver" is switched to false. Whwn you begin.... you're not (yet) over.
I'd call it "style"

Answer (score 1):

While either way works technically, the way the original code is written makes more sense lexically:

```
while (!isOver)
```

ie, keep doing this until it's finished.  If you want to switch to using the 2nd block, a name change of the variable would help, eg:

```
while (notOver)
```

It makes no difference to the execution of the code, but a world of difference to future readers/maintainers of the code.

Personally I'd stick with the first one, using the features of the language to define the not (`!`), as when you're setting the flag, I believe this:

```
isOver = true;
```

is easier to read and make more sense of than:

```
notOver = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first version of the code, `isOver` is initially set to false, meaning the loop is not over and should continue to run.

The while loop condition checks if isOver is not `true` (`!isOver`), so the loop will continue running until `isOver` becomes `true`.
This happens when the user doesn't enter a name, at which point `isOver` is set to true, and the loop ends.

In the second version of the code, you've inverted the logic. `isOver` is now initially set to `true`, meaning the loop is over.

However, the condition in the while loop is now checking if `isOver` is `true`, so the loop will continue running as long as `isOver` is `true`. This time, when the user doesn't enter a name, `isOver` is set to `false`, and the loop ends.

The reason to use `false` in the first place has more to do with readability and intuitive understanding of the code. Most developers will understand the flag `isOver` to represent completion, so having it set to `true` when the task is complete makes sense. This is why the initial state of `isOver` is false in the first place - because the task (in this case, the while loop) is not yet complete. If you invert this logic, it might confuse other developers who read your code later.